# Cube Measure groups, Measures and Dimensions visualised

Tags: mdx, dmv

The following query (used in Excel VBA) gets the measuregroups and the dimensions from a cube, but not the measures. I would like to tie the dimensions to their measures and not just the measuregroup. Is that possible?

```
SQLstr = "SELECT  [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] AS [Dimension]" & _
                " ,[MEASUREGROUP_NAME] AS [MeasureGroup]" & _
                " FROM $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS" & _
                " WHERE [CUBE_NAME] ='" & CubeName & "'" & _
                " AND NOT [DIMENSION_IS_FACT_DIMENSION]" & _
                " ORDER BY [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME]"
```

Comment: The relationships are between dimensions and measure groups, probably you may join all measure to measure group and get the information.

Comment: $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES gets you the measures but as far as I know you can't join it in one query

Comment: Is there some way to join in more queries? As far as I know mdschema_measures has no info on dimensions so no way to join